# Datagridview: How to change color of alternate rows having cell value alternate days?

Tags: vb.net

Respected Sir,
I have  a datagridview filled with data having various timestamps in one column

[image]

And trying to colour rows in range of alternate days like the image above. So far, i am trying like this

```
Private Sub alternateDaysRows()
        For i As Integer = 1 To Me.datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1
            If i > 1 Then
                Dim myLastRowDate As Date
                myLastRowDate = CType(Me.datagridview1.Rows(Me.datagridview1.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(2).Value, DateTime).Date
                myCountDate = myLastRowDate.AddDays(1)
                For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.datagridview1.Rows
                    If CType(row.Cells(2).Value, DateTime).Date = myCountDate Then
                        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
```

any suggestions ?

yours faithfully
Murulimadhav

Comment: one of the row paint events may work. mot clear what the problem is though

Comment: So what is happening? Is no row showing a different background color or are they all colored the same? Furthermore, are the rows ordered by date?

Comment: only one row get colored only (the next day of the "myLastRowDate"),  and ya rows are ordered by date from the query only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines may do what you want:

```
Private Sub alternateDaysRows()
    Dim myLastRow As DataGridViewRow = Nothing
    Dim myLastColor = Color.Yellow
    Dim isFirstRow As Boolean = True

    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows
        If myLastRow IsNot Nothing Then
            If DateTime.Parse(myLastRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString).Date <> DateTime.Parse(row.Cells(0).Value.ToString).Date Then
                myLastColor = If(myLastColor = Color.Yellow, Color.Red, Color.Yellow)
            End If
        End If

        myLastRow = row
        row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = myLastColor
    Next
```

This assumes that the cells are sorted in date order and that the values are convertable to a date. It alternates when the date changes rather than on every other day but would highlight when a different day is being viewed.

Comment: yes the cells are sorted in date order from query only and its working great, fantastic logic, thanks a lot lot, yours faithfully, Murulimadhav